# Need help, Communication issues between vlans for my hp 2920

Tags: vlan

(vlan noob here! plz help)

I had a Voip install dumped on me at the last min, and I am having issues getting my vlans to communicate to each other.  We purchased a Hp 2920 switch which says it has layer 3 capabilities..

I have 2 Vlans, My defaut vlan 1 where all my client workstations are, and vlan 2 which is used for voice.

I have configured each vlan with their own ip's and such as shown in the config below; however, the only time can get my workstation from vlan 1 to ping vlan 2 is when I change the my ipv4 adapter default gateway settings to 10.0.1.210 which is the Ip address from my vlan 1.  My ability to ping vlan 2 is very limited because I can only ping the vlan 2 Ip address(10.0.2.210).  I can't ping any systems on the vlan 2 from vlan 1.

Now, I am able to ping both vlans and clients to the vlans via the console of the hp 2920, so that is working I guess.

The reason I need workstations to talk to my vlan 2 if needed is because our phone system and remote phone we need to get setup requires this ability to talk to the phone system on Vlan2 from vlan1.

My config is as follows: Show Run

```
hostname "HP-2920-48G-POE+"
module 1 type j9729a
ip default-gateway 10.0.1.1 ---> Sonicwall Firewall
ip dns server-address priority 1 10.0.1.252 ---> Dhcp server and other services
ip routing
snmp-server community "public" unrestricted
oobm
   ip address dhcp-bootp
   exit
vlan 1
   name "DEFAULT_VLAN"
   no untagged 46,48
   untagged 1-45,47,A1-A2,B1-B2
   ip address 10.0.1.210 255.255.255.0
   exit
vlan 2
   name "Voice Vlan"
   untagged 46,48
   tagged 1-45,47
   ip address 10.0.2.210 255.255.255.0
   qos priority 6
   voice
   exit
```

I would like to thank you in advance for the help because I really need it.  I am drawing up blanks, and no matter how hard I look on the internet I can't seem to get it setup correctly.

Also Here is my ip routes: Show Ip Routes

```
Destination        Gateway         VLAN Type      Sub-Type   Metric     Dist.
------------------ --------------- ---- --------- ---------- ---------- -----
10.0.1.0/24        DEFAULT_VLAN    1    connected            1          0
10.0.2.0/24        Voice Vlan      2    connected            1          0
127.0.0.0/8        reject               static               0          0
127.0.0.1/32       lo0                  connected            1          0
```

I think there is need for a route here, so the traffic can bridge the gap, but I dunno.

Thanks again :)

Comment: The host gateway must be on the same network as the host because the gateway is the host on the network that knows how to get off the network.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, forgive my derpyness, but when you say host gateway are you referring to 10.0.1.210, 10.0.2.210 or 10.0.1.1?

Comment: The gateway address of the router for the network. If the VLAN 1 router address is `10.1.0.1`, and the VLAN 2 router address is `10.2.0.1`, then those are the gateways for the respective VLANs/networks.

Comment: What device is your router? Does it support vLANs and multiple interfaces? If you want to avoid static routes on every device on your network then you need to “trunk” vLAN 1 and 2 to your router and configure it with an IP address on vLAN 1 of 10.0.1.1 like it is currently, and an address on vLAN 2 of 10.0.2.1 then allow it to route the traffic for both networks. Or, you’ll have to reconfigure your network so that all traffic goes through, and is routed by the switch, first. That means making the switch be 10.0.1.1 and 10.0.2.1 and adding vLAN 3 for the connection back to the router. Complex.

Comment: Ron: Very cool that helps some, I have a sonic wall firewall (10.0.1.1) connected to my cable modem.
Appleoddity: My router device is a sonic wall tz215, and I am not sure, I will have to look at it.  I read over the rest of your post, and its a bit difficult to totally understand.  do you by chance know of a good article that outlines the points ur making so i can take time to digest it?

Also Thanks guys much apprecated

Comment: Hey everyone, When I was reading the outlined information to configure my hp 2920 switch from my phone vendor they mentioned to me and I quote "Using Policy Based VLAN programming-NOT PORT BASED" does this mean anything to you guys.  All I have ever been able to locate is port based in any of my settings.  If policy based vlan programming is a thing does this happen on the hp 2920 or on my sonciwall router?

Comment: I did want to point out that my network is really small. I setting up static routes really that hard?  I have 1 sonicwall and 1 l3 hp 2920 switch.  I am super frustrated that its not a simple button that you click in a web interface that says forward packs from vlan1 to vlan2 and vice versa.  Please someone help me get this done I am way out of my understanding and everywhere I look on the internet says do what you have done and it works. I have even seen ppl say how to do u turn it off.  I really don't want to run all my inter vlan traffic through my sonciwall

Comment: When I set my workstation gateway to 10.0.1.210 i can ping 10.0.2.210 just can't ping any devices on that side namely the phone controller.  I can ping it just fine from the cli it would seem like there has to be a simple solution to this.

Comment: As you can ping your PBX from CLI, it's most likely PBX doesn't have gateway set, rather than vlan thing. Try "ping 10.0.2.x(your PBX) source 10.0.1.210" on your CLI and see if it works.

Comment: Shogo: Thanks for your reply buddy, I agree.  After many hours of racking my brain on this I thought back to when we setup the phone system with the techs, and they asked me what the gateway was for the phone system, and I gave them 10.0.2.1 and not the 10.0.2.210, so I am thinking that the reason my pings fail is because the phone controller can't send me a response due to the wrong gateway being configured.  I am waiting on them now to change the default gateway, so I can test my connection status.

Comment: @Shane  that is not the answer. This is basic networking. If you use .210 as the gateway on vLAN 2 then you’ll have to use .210 as the gateway on vLAN 1 and that means that nobody gets on the internet.

Comment: WOOOOOT! Hey everyone, I got it working! thanks so much for your help.  I am grateful. The shout out for the right thought is Shogo2022.  It was that my phone controller gateway didn't have the correct Ip to return my pings.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one potential setup. This is most likely what you want to do, it will require the least amount of reconfiguration and change to the network.

The key here is that the Sonicwall routes packets between the two subnets. You have to have something route packets between the two networks - and if you don't want to setup static routes on everything, then that means it has to be your default gateway.

[image]

Sorry, I mixed up the phones and computer on the opposite vLAN. But, the idea is the same.